# Turtle Circle makes lines disappear

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe, turtle-graphics

I am working on a Tic-Tac-Toe game using Turtle and ran in to an error that I haven't been able to solve with Google, the Python docs, or other help including existing StackOverflow questions.

When I invoke my `draw_circle()` function all drawn lines on the **click-able board** disappear, this includes the grid lines and Xs if there are any on the board.

The turtles that are used to draw the lines remain on the board.

This is what a completed game looks like:

[image]

```
def draw_circle(x, y):
  global count
  global circle
  radius = 20
  yertle = init_turtle()
  yertle.color("red")
  yertle.setpos(x, y-radius)
  yertle.down()
  yertle.showturtle()  # Remove this later, only used for demonstration
  yertle.circle(radius)  # Error occurs here, when the turtle should draw.
  circle = False
  count += 1
```

**Full code here**: https://bugs.python.org/file34638/aoeu.py
You need to run the code I provide because the issue is not reproducible by just firing up turtle and drawing a circle.

Someone answered and deleted their answer and it pointed out that if you set the circle radius to 200 then you can see that the circle is in fact drawing.
Because of this I believe that the bug is related to the click-able turtle object that acts as my Tic-Tac-Toe board.
Screenshot of the bahavior when radius = 200: http:// i. imgur. com/ gYeOlnT. png

Any help is appreciated and if anything is not clear I will try to clarify to the best of my ability.
Thank you.

Link to bug on Python bug tracker: http:// bugs. python. org/ issue21077

ESL:
Speed(0) + Click-able turtle object = Make not work.

Comment: I don't know why your circles and Xs aren't showing up, but a general suggestion is to reuse the same turtle, rather than creating a new one for every shape. In traditional turtle graphics, there's only one turtle ever!

Comment: My Xs are showing up just fine, but are destroyed when the draw_circle() function is executed.  I'll rewrite the code to use the same turtle, but if anyone has insight as to why this method is not working properly I'd really appreciate hearing it.

Comment: **Is there a way to see what turtle is doing in the background?** I should be able to spot a difference in what happens if I use turtle.dot() vs turtle.circle(), yes?

Comment: I don't know if you can see what the turtle is doing visually, but you can always look in the `turtle` module's code to try to understand the difference between `circle` and `dot`. Just look for `turtle.py` in your Python installation's `lib` directory.

Comment: Thanks Blckknight, I'll check those functions out. I figured out the real cause of the problem, setting speed to 0!